# Notification in Kotlin repeating every day at the same time

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-notifications

None of the other Stackoverflow code I found works. All is either Java, or I'm too dumb to make it work.

How to fire notification at the same time every day? So basic thing and I can't find anything for Kotlin.

Comment: "How to fire notification at the same time every day?" -- generally, you don't. Specific-timed background events are unreliable, as they are abused in ways that drain the battery. As such, things like Doze mode, app standby, and manufacturer-specific power managers interfere with such events. I recommend that you try to rework your plans to avoid the need for specific times. That being said, you are welcome to experiment with `AlarmManager` (e.g., `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`) and see if it works well enough for your needs.

Comment: And what do apps that send you notification reminder every day at the time you set do then???

Comment: Alarm clock apps [use `setAlarmClock()` on `AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)). If you are creating an alarm clock app, you are welcome to use this. Some apps that rely on Internet access might use server-sent high-priority Firebase Cloud Messaging events. And, as I mentioned, you can try `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` and see if suffices for what you need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this code to schedule showing notification each day at 22:00 (or any other hour in `HOUR_TO_SHOW_PUSH`):

```
private val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
private val alarmPendingIntent by lazy {
    val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)
}
private const val HOUR_TO_SHOW_PUSH = 22

fun schedulePushNotifications() {
    val calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance().apply {
        if (get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= HOUR_TO_SHOW_PUSH) {
            add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        }

        set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR_TO_SHOW_PUSH)
        set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
        set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
    }

    alarmManager.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        calendar.timeInMillis,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
        alarmPendingIntent
    )
}
```

It will trigger `BroadcastReceiver` called `AlarmReceiver`, so you'll have to implement it too:

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        showPushNotification() // implement showing notification in this function
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register it in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name="com.your-package-name.AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true"/>
```

Also note that to schedule these notifications you have to call `schedulePushNotifications()`, meaning that the app has to be launched at least once after each reboot. If you want your notifications to be shown after a reboot without launching your app, consider implementing `BootReceiver` that will be triggered immediately after reboot:

```
class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED") {
            schedulePushNotifications()
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register it in AndroidManifest.xml too:

```
<receiver android:name="com.your-package-name.BootReceiver" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```